# Protocol relative url not pulling up images on IE, FF, and OPERA

Tags: images, urls, ssl

I'm running into an issue where I'm using the protocol relative url for the images from the wordpress Amazon s3 plugin on my SSL pages. In Chrome, all images are loading fine but when I tested it on IE, FF, and Opera, the images aren't showing up.

Here is what I inserted into the theme option image input field:

```
//www3.mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/my_logo.png
```

Does anyone know why it's causing this issue? I searched the web and couldn't find a clear answer.

Thanks for your time,
Hal

**Output of HTML**

```
<a href="https://www.mydomain.com">                 
<img src="//www3.mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/my_logo.png" 
alt="mydomain" class="normal_logo">
</a>
```

**Solution**

Since I'm using the Amazon s3 plugin, I'm required to use the s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/key domain name if I'm pulling contents into a SSL page. Hope this helps if anyone is having problems.

Comment: What is the output of the html where your relative url is being used?

Comment: When I hovered over the image url in FIREFOX, i get popup signal saying, "Failed to load given URL." Then I copied and pasted it into the browser and the image does show up with the HTTP:// protocol.

Comment: I figured out the solution.

Comment: To help other users of this site, please add your solution as an **Answer** to this question, and then, when you're able -- I think the delay is 48 hours -- mark the answer as **Accepted**.